# print a message in Ansible loop

Tags: ansible

I wrote an Ansible code to disable 30 to 40 services.
Please find below code:

```yaml
- service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
  with_items:
    - service 1
    - service n
```

Now I need to print a version numbers on top of every service in `with_items` loop. I've tried `msg:` and `shell: echo` but both of them are failing.

Comment: *I need to print a version numbers* > where would that version number be coming from?

Comment: that version number only for our understanding that's part of requirement, we need to print it but it's not coming from any where

Comment: So you have like an hardcoded lists that says: `service 1: x.y.z`, `service n: a.b.c`, ...?

Comment: yes i have predefined version numbers that i need to print on top of every service and every service have different version number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this adding a version in a dictionary, next to your services, then use the [`label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) option to control the loop output.

The task:

```yaml
- service:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.version }}"
  loop:
    - name: service 1
      version: a.b.c
    - name: service n
      version: x.y.z
```

Should give you an output looking like:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [shell] ********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=a.b.c)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x.y.z)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You can even combine information in the `label` if you feel like so:

```yaml
- service:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}: {{ item.version }}"
  loop:
    - name: service 1
      version: a.b.c
    - name: service n
      version: x.y.z
```

Will give an output of:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [shell] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=service 1: a.b.c)
ok: [localhost] => (item=service n: x.y.z)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```